# entering 1 jabber account on 2 devices. Both keep getting online and offline

Tags: android, ejabberd

I have a jabber ID which is logged in multiple devices
I want that the new session should retain and previous session should close permenantly
but both devices are connnecting to server. Both are getting online and offline
I have put Max user session to 1 and resource conflict to closenew
but the issue still stands

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

One XMPP **account** can have multiple opened **sessions**, each session will have a different **resource**.

If a new session wants to login to the account using a resource already being used by another session, then ejabberd follows the [resource_conflict option](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/toplevel/#resource-conflict).

Some Jabber/XMPP clients, when they get disconnected by the server, attempt to login again. In that case, ejabberd closes the other session. Then the other client attempts to login again, and you end with a loop, both clients attempting to login. This is a problem in your clients, that attempt to login.

What do you expect ejabberd to do in that case??

Something similar happens with the [max_user_sessions` option](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/basic/#limiting-opened-sessions)

If you want to prevent those infinite loops:

- Configure your client to NOT attempt to relogin when they are closed
- Set `resource_conflict: closenew` and you will have the new client attempting to login all the time, the old session will remain alive.
- Tell the clients to use different resources, so they get different sessions, both connected at the same time with no conflict.